# PostgreSQL JSONB grouping array values inside a hash

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

We have a PostgreSQL `jsonb` column containing hashes which in turn contain arrays of values:

```
id | hashes
---------------
1  | {"sources"=>["a","b","c"], "ids"=>[1,2,3]}
2  | {"sources"=>["b","c","d","e","e"], "ids"=>[1,2,3]}
```

What we'd like to do is create a `jsonb` query which would return

```
code | count
---------------
"a"  | 1
"b"  | 2
"c"  | 2
"d"  | 1
"e"  | 2
```

we've been trying something along the lines of

```
SELECT jsonb_to_recordset(hashes->>'sources')
```

but that's not working - any help with this hugely appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup (should be a part of the question, note the proper json syntax):

```
create table a_table (id int, hashes jsonb);
insert into a_table values
(1, '{"sources":["a","b","c"], "ids":[1,2,3]}'),
(2, '{"sources":["b","c","d","e","e"], "ids":[1,2,3]}');
```

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

```
select code, count(code)
from
    a_table,
    jsonb_array_elements(hashes->'sources') sources(code)
group by 1
order by 1;

 code | count 
------+-------
 "a"  |     1
 "b"  |     2
 "c"  |     2
 "d"  |     1
 "e"  |     2
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT h, count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(hashes->'sources') AS h FROM mytable
  ) sub
GROUP BY h
ORDER BY h;
```

Answer (score 0):

We finally got this working this way:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(hashes->'sources') as s1,
count(jsonb_array_elements_text(hashes->'sources'))
FROM a_table
GROUP BY s1;
```

but Klin's solution is more complete and both Klin and Patrick got there quicker than us (thank you both) - so points go to them.